# PostgreSQL Replication on a daily basis

Tags: postgresql, replication, slony

With PostgreSQL, I want to replicate a subset of all tables from Database A to B, but only once a day. Since I do not know what to search for: is there a technical term for such a scenario? Does e.g. [Slony-I](http://www.slony.info/) support this?

Comment: Did You mean the replication only will sync one time per day ? Then You will have accumulated transaction to sync. Why would You want such scenario

Comment: @SoniHarriz Yes. Roughly speaking, database A (read/write) is a preview for database B (read). At one time per day the current state needs to be synced to database B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by stopping the replication, which is the slon daemon. By stopping the daemon, sync event get accumulated on sl_log tables on master. When slon get started again, this accumulated logs will get synced to slave.

Hope it helps.

Comment: How do I know when to stop the daemon? Won't `sl_log` get new entries during the process so that it potentially never gets empty? In this case, I would never know when to stop the replication.

Comment: daemon and sl_log are mutually exclusive, sl_log get accumulated from trigger processed by postgres itself, while daemon sync the log to slave. You can stop the daemon anytime, the logs still get accumulated.